# Is there a way to set the size of an EPS image which is embedded in a PostScript?

Tags: size, scale, postscript, eps

I have an EPS image (Encapsulated PostScript) and I embedded it in a PostScript. I'd like to set it's size for example in millimeters like 50x50 or something. I found a way to resize it with the `scale` keyword like

`.7 .7 scale`

but that way I only can give a rate to it not a concrete size.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostScript is device independent, so you aren't supposed to try and set things to a specific size in terms of output. This allows devices to use differently sized media (for example including hardware margins), or different resolutions, and still produce the desired output.

Bearing in mind that EPS files are intended for use by applications, that will embed the EPS in their own output, its important that the EPS itself be scalable. The application can read the BoundingBox from the EPS file, and then scale that into its own co-ordinate system so that the EPS fits a specific size at a particular position on the output.

Basically, *you* need to work out what scale factor to use, by taking the EPS BoundingBox and working out what scale factor will fit that into the area you want it to cover on your output.